# Include view to view in Codeignitter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I created a tema.php page. It has header and footer in itself.
It is getting others page by it -> `<?php $this->load->view($tema);?>`in tema.php.

Now I create blog post detail page. It's name is yazi1.php. It's working right. Header and footer has come to page. And I get datas from database. But now it's give me 5 error. I write errors under it.

Here is my codes ->

Dersler.php (Controller)

```
public function yazi1($slug = NULL){
            $veri['ders'] = $this->Ders_model->getir_dersS($slug);

            if(empty($veri['ders'])){
                show_404();
            }
            $veri['baslik'] = $veri['ders']['baslik'];
            $beta_veri['tema'] = $this->load->view('yazi1',$veri);
            $this->load->view('tema',$beta_veri);
        }
```

Ders_model.php (Model)

```
    public function getir_dersS($slug = FALSE){
        if($slug === FALSE){
            $query = $this->db->get('ders');
            return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('ders',array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
```

yazi1.php (view)

```
<?php echo $ders['baslik'];?>
<?php echo $ders['icerik'];?>
```

Routes.php ->

```
$route['ders/(:any)'] = 'dersler/yazi1/$1';
```

Errors... ->

1-

```
Severity: Warning

Message: pathinfo() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 900

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\application\views\tema.php
Line: 63
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\application\controllers\Dersler.php
Line: 19
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

2-

```
Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 905

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\application\views\tema.php
Line: 63
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\application\controllers\Dersler.php
Line: 19
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

3-

```
Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 907

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\application\views\tema.php
Line: 63
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\application\controllers\Dersler.php
Line: 19
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

4-

```
Severity: Warning

Message: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\application\views): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 968

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\application\views\tema.php
Line: 63
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\application\controllers\Dersler.php
Line: 19
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

5-

```
Severity: Warning

Message: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\application\views\' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 968

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\application\views\tema.php
Line: 63
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\application\controllers\Dersler.php
Line: 19
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\1koddenizi\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Comment: what is `'yazi1'` and `'tema'` view ?

Comment: Please do some formatting its hard to read your error log.

Comment: yazi1.php is post detail page. tema.php has  header and footer. I included yazi1.php to tema.php

Comment: tema.php view. Can you please add tema.php file in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a `TRUE` flag when nesting a view to another view, so it will return the content rather than display it :

```
$beta_veri['tema'] = $this->load->view('yazi1', $veri, TRUE);
$this->load->view('tema', $beta_veri);
```

Comment: thank you so much! It's work :D but now its give me a new error Unable to load the requested file: .php can you help?